# Prevent escaping backslash in template literal

Tags: javascript

I don't want backslash character to escape when using the template literal.

**Expected** - `AND a.site_id IN ( MI\'S HOUSE,dwwd)`

**Getting**  - `AND a.site_id IN ( MI'S HOUSE,dwwd)`

```js
var payload = {
  site: ['MI\'S HOUSE', "dwwd"]
}

let sql = `AND a.site_id IN ( ${payload.site}) `;
console.log(sql)
```

Comment: Do you have control over the `payload` data?

Comment: no i don't have @YongQuan

Comment: The string in your payload **does not contain** any backslashes. It contains a `'` that is escaped because this string literal uses single quotes. Also, you need to **PROPERLY** serialize the string when adding it like that into a Query; can't emphasize this enough. Your snippet is a prime example on how **not** to do SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var payload = { site: [ "MI\\'S HOUSE","dwwd" ]}

sql = "";
sql += `AND a.site_id IN ( ${payload.site}) `;
console.log(sql)
```